# How to receive message for user specific using signalR c# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr.client

I have an MVC application.

I have implemented singalR to receive live notifications but how to get only user specific notifications.

NotificationSend.cs

```
public class NotificationSend : Hub
{
    private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationSend>();
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType> MyUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        MyUsers.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, new MyUserType() { ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId });
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        MyUserType garbage;

        MyUsers.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId, out garbage);

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public static void SendToUser(string messageText)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.Client(MyUsers.Keys.ToList().FirstOrDefault()).Notification(messageText);
    }

    public static void StopLoader(string messageText)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.Client(MyUsers.Keys.ToList().FirstOrDefault()).Stoploader(messageText);
    }
}
public class MyUserType
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

    public async Task<ActionResult> SaveData()
        {
         foreach (var mydata in DataList)
                {
                   // save data code and show below message on UI
                   NotificationSend.SendToUser(mydata.Name + ": Data saved");
```

I'm able to get notification on UI perfectly fine but problem is

> If user A using his own machine and his login he should get only his notification , I know webapp url is same.

for that i make below change but not any notification is visible after this change.

```
string UserID = User.Identity.Name;
hubContext.Clients.User(UserID).Notification(mydata.Name + ": Data saved");
```

Layout.js

```
$(function () {
            var notification = $.connection.notificationSend;
            console.log(notification);
            notification.client.Notification = function (Count) {
                $('#liveupdate').empty();
                $('#liveupdate').show();
                $('#liveupdate').append(Count);
            };
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
                console.log("Connected Successfully");
            }).fail(function (response) {
                console.log("not connected" + response);
            });
        });
```

Comment: you're testing multiple users on same machine and probably same browser instance?

Comment: yes in multiple tabs

Comment: maybe try switching browsers for each user or browser profile or if possible try a different user from a different machine

Comment: for a message to be sent back to the client the Server needs to know socket connection information and by using same browser instance the resultant address is same i think, that's why a message is pushed to all tabs, SignalR is working fine

Comment: but it should be different for all users ? can anyone help here if user login is different i should not get other users notification.

Comment: as you said you're using the same browser instance means the same socket connection for different users how would the server know about specific user aside from socket connection info. have you tried it with different browsers, different users?

Comment: If another user is logged in on another machine and do some operation that notification also I can able to see on my machine if this web url is open on my machine..

Comment: my requirement is user A is login using his credential to dev url and saving some data to he should see data is saving...  not B user if is also login using B's login on dev url. Url is same but user and its login and machine is different

Comment: where are you registring individual users in `SignalR` ? and what does this line do `hubContext.Clients.All.Notification(mydata.Name + ": Data saved");`

Comment: have you implemented `OnConnected()` and `OnDisconnected()` in your `Hub`?

Comment: not registering seperate users how to do that,?
above line will send notification to all clients

Comment: I will updated my new implemented code

Comment: for starters make a static class to persisit `HubContext` instance in memory and add a group to hub based on user's id or email that could identify him/her uniquely then use the context to push the notification to that specific group that would contain only that user

Comment: please check my updated code I can able to get the notifications but only problem  i want to tackle is when any another user is login to same url with another username he should not get any other users notification

Comment: i'm missing very little part please check and guide me

Comment: I've added my answer , take a look if this make sense

Comment: thanks i will check and revert

Comment: did the solution work?

Comment: unable to understand do we need this `NotificationsResourceHandler` cant we use something like `hubContext.Clients.User` inside `OnConnected` and `SendToUser` ? it will make it simple ?

Comment: this handler class is static as mentioned earlier it'll hold a reference to the context of a specific hub and keep the record of registered groups, that way `SignalR` would know which connections are valid and where to send the notification to

Comment: thanks for your effort but I can change the complete implementation right now any chance we can made change in my current code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a static class its instance will be created once and will persist information in memory like the instance of context

```
public static class NotificationsResourceHandler
{
    private static readonly IHubContext myContext;       
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Groups;



    static NotificationsResourceHandler()
    {
        myContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();   
        Groups = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public static void BroadcastNotification(dynamic model, NotificationType notificationType, string userName)
    {
        myContext.Clients.Group(userName).PushNotification(new { Data = model, Type = notificationType.ToString() });
    }
}
```

and in your Hub

```
[HubName("yourHub")]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var userEmail = Context.QueryString["useremail"]?.ToLower();
        if (userEmail == null) throw new Exception("Unable to Connect to Signalr hub");

        if (NotificationsResourceHandler.Groups.All(x => x.Value != userEmail))
        {
            NotificationsResourceHandler.Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userEmail);
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userEmail);
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        NotificationsResourceHandler.Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        Clients.All.removeConnection(Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

Notification will be pushed to individual groups, for your problem you should create a separate group for each user as provided in code.

Comment: thanks for your effort but I can change the complete implementation right now any chance we can made change in my current code ?

Comment: well I can try, I had this solution working for me that's why I posted it, I can try to get your code working, in the meantime, you can set up this solution and keep the previous one if this works then transform yours with this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example code in VB.Net (you may convert it to C#):

```
Public Class SignalRHub
    Inherits Hub

    Private Shared hubContext As IHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of SignalRHub)()

    Public Sub SendToAll(ByVal msg As String)
        hubContext.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(msg)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SendToUser(ByVal user As String, ByVal msg As String)
        hubContext.Clients.Group(user).addNewMessageToPage(msg)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As Task
        Dim name As String = Context.User.Identity.Name
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name)
        Return MyBase.OnConnected()
    End Function

End Class
```

You have to use Group. Basically what I do is 1 group is for 1 user. Define by the username.

Then just call the function:

```
Dim user As User = idb.Users.Where(Function(a) a.id = userid).FirstOrDefault
Dim msg as string = "Any notification message"
SignalRHub.SendToUser(user.UserName, msg)
```

Lastly, javascript code to trigger that:

```
var notification = $.connection.signalRHub;
notification.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (msg) {
    $("#notification").prepend(msg);
}
```

ID notification where you want to put the notification message.

Comment: I tried but no notification i'm getting :( can you help me with c# code which will work for specific user login, other user should not want to see others notification.